# Check a minecraft server's difficulty?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is it possible for me to check what difficulty level is current set to on a vanilla (or almost vanilla) minecraft server?

I do have my own server, and I know I can simply check the server.properties file and restart the server, but is there a way any other players (standard players or OPs) can check the current setting being used on a server?

For example, say another OP changes the difficulty with the `/difficulty` command, how can I easily check this? I know I could search through the console output, but this isn't too easy with the server that I rent, and could other players determine the current difficulty setting without having to guess based upon gameplay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, there isn't  a way to check without the use of external plugins.

Comment: Of course in @Bryan's scenario, he could just make a habit of overwriting it with (what he has set as) default each time he logs in.

Answer (score 11):

let yourself starve.  If you can't starve then it's peaceful.  If u remain with 10 hearts (health doesn't drain when starving), it's easy.  If you get taken down to 1/2 heart then it's normal.  If you die then it's hard.

Comment: Just to clarify, in Easy, your health gets drained down to 10 *health points*, which is 5 full hearts.